# Cocoa Touch Framework with third-party static libraries and frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I'm developing a Cocoa Touch Framework which is used a couple of third-party static libraries and frameworks. For some of them I have a source code. For others I'm don't.
The issue is when someone who uses my framework wants to use the same third-party static libraries and frameworks, he will encounter with console logs like:

```
Class <ClassName> is implemented in both <Path to my framework> and <Path to my app>. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

My framework is written on Objective-C.

How can I completely hide third-party libraries and frameworks inside my own dynamic framework so that developers who are using my framework also can use the same third-party static libraries and frameworks without any conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are seeing in the log is the result of you compiling the source files of the third-party library for both your framework's target and your app's target. You'll most likely see the source files in the `Compile Sources` build phase for both targets.

To fix this, remove the files from the app's `Compile Sources` build phase, as it is unnecessary to have them there. It is not necessary to link/compile libraries for your app that have already been linked/compiled into your framework.

Comment: I created a new dynamic framework with third-party static framework inside. After that I created a new XCode project and added my dynamic framework to it. All works ok. After that I added the same third-party static framework to this project and I see console logs about duplicated classes. I'm not using source files, I'm using already compiled frameworks